# Aceptar un solo elemento arrastrable dentro de mi contenedor

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, sortable

Estoy trbajando con la libreria sortable en Reactjs, tengo una lista de elementos que arrastro hacia un contenedor, quisiera poder inhabilitar mi contenedor una vez que ingrese un elemento arrastrado. Es decir si ya arrastre un elemento, que no permita agregar mas en ese contenedor. Osea que solo acepte un elemento, no mas.

Este es el componente que tiene la lista de elementos que estoy enviando a los contenedores:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";
import { getData } from "../services/api_aralsoft";
import "../assets/styles/ButtonListContainer.css";

const ButtonListContainer = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getData_api = async () => {
    const res = await getData();
    const arrOfArray = Object.entries(res);
    const arraOfKeys = Object.keys(arrOfArray[0][1]);
    setData(arraOfKeys);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData_api();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="itemSelect">
        <ReactSortable
          list={data}
          setList={setData}
          group={{ name: "selectedButton" }}
          animation={150}
        >
          {!data
            ? "Cargando..."
            : data.map((item, index) => (
                <button className="btnSelect" key={index}>
                  {item}
                </button>
              ))}
        </ReactSortable>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ButtonListContainer;
```

Este es el componente que recibe los elementos arrastrados; Aqui es donde quiero evitar que se agreguen mas de 1.

```
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";
import "../assets/styles/Container.css";

const Container = () => {
  const [row, setRow] = useState([]);
  const [column, setColumn] = useState([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  
  return (
    <div className="bottomContainer">
      <section className="itemsSelected">
        <div className="containerVertical">
          <div className="containerR">
            Filas
            <ReactSortable
              list={row}
              setList={setRow}
              group={{ name: "selectedButton", pull: true }}
            >
              {!row
                ? "Cargando..."
                : row.map((item, index) => (
                    <button
                      className="btnSelect"
                      key={index}
                      ref={(button) => addToArrayOfSelectedButtons(button)}
                    >
                      {item}
                    </button>
                  ))}
            </ReactSortable>
          </div>
        </div>
        <article className="container_col_val">
          <div className="containerHorizontal">
            <div className="containerR">
              Columnas
              <ReactSortable
                list={column}
                setList={setColumn}
                group={{ name: "selectedButton", pull: true }}
              >
                {!column
                  ? "Cargando..."
                  : column.map((item, index) => (
                      <button
                        className="btnSelect"
                        key={index}
                        ref={(button) => addToArrayOfSelectedButtons(button)}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </button>
                    ))}
              </ReactSortable>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="containerHorizontal">
            <div className="containerR">
              Valores
              <ReactSortable
                list={values}
                setList={setValues}
                group={{ name: "selectedButton", pull: true }}
              >
                {!values
                  ? "Cargando..."
                  : values.map((item, index) => (
                      <button
                        className="btnSelect"
                        key={index}
                        ref={(button) => addToArrayOfSelectedButtons(button)}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </button>
                    ))}
              </ReactSortable>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>

    </div>
  );
};
export default Container;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes limitar el número de elementos que se pueden arrastrar y soltar en un contenedor utilizando la propiedad accept de ReactSortable. La propiedad accept espera una función que toma el nuevo elemento a ser arrastrado y soltado como argumento y devuelve true si se permite agregar el elemento al contenedor o false en caso contrario.

Por ejemplo, si deseas permitir que solo se agregue un elemento al contenedor, puedes utilizar la siguiente implementación:

```
<ReactSortable
  accept={(item) => {
    return row.length < 1; // Permitir solo un elemento
  }}
  list={row}
  setList={setRow}
  group={{ name: "selectedButton", pull: true }}
>
  {!row
    ? "Cargando..."
    : row.map((item, index) => (
        <button
          className="btnSelect"
          key={index}
          ref={(button) => addToArrayOfSelectedButtons(button)}
        >
          {item}
        </button>
      ))}
</ReactSortable>
```

De esta manera, cuando intentes arrastrar un segundo elemento a este contenedor, se rechazará y no se agregará al contenedor.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me funciono. Se siguen agregando botones a los contenedores, básicamente no causo ningún efecto

Comment: de hecho estuve revisando la documentación y no vi esa propiedad por ningún lado, podrías darme mas información o donde me puedo apoyar!